# matplotlib - imshow 'extents' definiton killed plt.text

Tags: matplotlib

I am quite the novice at matplotlib, so bear with me.  I have the code below that plots a cylindrical equidistant grid of precipitation.  I set the 'extents' limits that finally aligned my basemap with the data.  Now, it appears to have "broken" my plt.text capability as I can no longer see the text 'Precipitation Rate (mm/hour)'.  Thanks for any help.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from pylab import *
import pickle

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

fp = open('uneven_rgb.pkl', 'rb')
uneven_rgb = pickle.load(fp)
fp.close()

num_lon = 1440
num_lat = 400
precipfile = "/Users/bolvin/3B43.20111001.7.HDF_precip.bin"

fileobj = open(precipfile, mode='rb') # Open file as read only binary

data = np.fromfile (fileobj, dtype ='f')

datat = np.reshape(data, (num_lon, num_lat), order = 'FORTRAN')

datam = datat * 24.0

my_cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('my_colormap',uneven_rgb)

plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))

mapproj = Basemap(projection = 'cyl', llcrnrlat=-50.0, llcrnrlon=0.0, urcrnrlat=50.0,urcrnrlon=360.0)

mapproj.drawcoastlines()
mapproj.drawcountries()

mapproj.drawparallels(np.array([-30.0, 0.0, 30.0]), labels=[0,0,0,0])
mapproj.drawmeridians(np.array([90.0, 180.0, 270.0]), labels=[0,0,0,0])

myplot = plt.imshow(datam.T, interpolation = 'nearest', cmap = my_cmap, vmin = 0.0, vmax = 20.0, extent = (0.0, 360.0, -50.0, 50.0))

plt.title('October 2011 3B43 Precipitation', fontsize = 36, y = 1.03)
plt.text(1.0, 435.0, 'Precipitation Rate (mm/hour)', size = 20)

cbar = plt.colorbar(myplot, orientation='horizontal', shrink = 0.5, pad = 0.03)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=20) 

plt.gca().axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.gca().axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

plt.show()

fileobj.close()
```

Comment: In the future you should try to make the code in your questions as succinct as possible.

Comment: I shall try, but please understand that python/matplotlib is new to me and I haven't developed the expertise to know exactly which lines of code are important and which lines aren't.  I erred on the side of caution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.text` gets as first argument the x and y coordinates on which your text will be put.

As you transformed your imshow plot into the bordes 0-360 for x and -50 to 50 for y, `y=435` is not in the plot anymore.

You can check your limits with `plt.gca().get_xlim().`

You have to move it somewhere in your limits.

Your defining the units you are plotting with this text, right? So the natural place for this would be the label of the colorbar:

```
cbar = plt.colorbar(myplot, orientation='horizontal', shrink = 0.5, 
                    pad = 0.03, label='Precipitation Rate (mm/hour)')
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much!  I have considered using plt.colorbar to annotate the plot, but I want to keep the option of placing it elsewhere.  Good karma to you!

Comment: if my post solved your problem, please feel free to mark my answer as the one that solved your problem and vote it up.

Comment: Don't have 15 points to vote up yet, but I did mark it as answered.

Comment: If you dont want to change the units provided to `text` you can also supply a transformation with `transform=ax.transAxes`. Then it will use axis coordinates instead of data coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  I'll keep this is mind.